Deploying a React application on GitHub Pages
I'm triyng to dpeloy my react application on Github Pages, but my 'npm run deploy' is not executing.
This project file is just a test application that is a brand new React App.
screen shot of vscode:

I've added the homepage, and the needed json scripts in order for it to run. I've pushed it to my github repository as "testing" - https://github.com/nicholas-ackley/testing
I cannot find anyone else who has a similar issue, any help is appreciated.

Hi there!
Not a pro here, but I deployed a react app last week on Pages and tried to compare your screenshot with my setup: you don't have any folder "build" in your app. I don't know which steps you realized, but I think you could try to follow these to make sure you have everything: https://github.com/gitname/react-gh-pages

@Lidia, that is not the problem, as OP is using Vite, and Vite actually builds the app and stores the compiled files in the dist directory

@MrSrv7 oh ok, I didn't know, thank you :)

From what I observed, I don't see the gh-pages dependency in your package.json file. So, install the gh-pages as a dev dependency by running npm install -D gh-pages. Then as you are using vite, in your vite.config.js, you need to add the base property to ./ the config file.
Refer to https://dev.to/rashidshamloo/deploying-vite-react-app-to-github-pages-35hf for a better understanding.
Also, github-actions and github-pages are experiencing degraded performance, which you can check out at https://www.githubstatus.com. Once the issue is fixed, you can try deploying your gh-pages repo.
